# controlling kafka listeners consumption

Tags: spring-kafka

in addition to previously asked questions about transactions, I'd like ask about controlling consumption: I have listener, which processes production data. Now something bad happens, and for any reason we want to have our app UP, but stop processing records. So I'd like to have option to manually (to begin with) stop consumers(I'm aware of ContainerStoppingErrorHandler). And after issue is resolved, to reposition them eventually and start them again.

I think I see a way how to do that, but I'd like if someone can confirm this to me, as there can be numerous gotchas. Whole process does not seem really easy, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something right, maybe there is better way.

So first things first, to be able to pause/stop consumers, I have to have acceess to MessageListenerContainer. Meaning, that in config I will create: ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory and (since 2.2) use it to create managed bean of ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer. This bean can be then used to start/stop consumers. Works. And once it's Concurrent... I assume, that what I pass into setupMessageListener must be instance of stateless class, so that it can be operated on from multiple threads/consumers. So if I want to have spring dependency injection, as I had before on bean with @KafkaListener annotated method, I can pass here instance of stateless singleton bean.

Now about repositioning: this seems to be easy. Just implement ConsumerSeekAware in messageListener class which was registered via setupMessageListener and store callback. Then you can just autowire ConsumerSeekAware messageListener singleton, and do the seek. Relevant MessageListenerContainer, regardless of partitions/concurrency settings should do the seek. Because when ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer starts with concurrency bigger than 1, then it starts multiple KafkaMessageListenerContainer a) either on all partitions(?), but since all share same groupId, just one consumer will consume the message, or b) each KafkaMessageListenerContainer will have some partitions subset. But in seek, we have to specify topic+partition+offset, so in either case seek should be picked up by appropriate KafkaMessageListenerContainer.

Right?

I'm aware this is intimidating text/question, but maybe this could be useful for someone else as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create your own containers

```
@KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = " ... "
```

Then, get a reference to the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` (auto wire etc).

then

```
registry.getListenerContainer("foo").stop();
```

or

```
registery.stop();
```

to stop all `@KafkaListener`s.

When concurrency is > 1; you need at least that many partitions, otherwise some consumers will be idle.

Partitions are distributed across the consumers by Kafka; the callback will be invoked by each one, with the list of partitions to which it has been assigned.